# Select a column default value into a variable in Pl/PgSQL

Tags: postgresql, triggers, plpgsql

I'm trying to implement a generic trigger procedure to enable a sort a versioning scheme on tables. Tables all have **version** and **current** fields. On updates, in some situations based on a condition, i want to create a new version of a row instead of updating the old one. I'm having trouble getting the default value for the primary key field (always **id**).

Here's what i've done:

```
CREATE FUNCTION version_trigger() RETURNS trigger AS $$
DECLARE
    id_default text;
    id_value text;

BEGIN
    IF version_condition() THEN
        old.current = false;

        -- I can read the default value
        SELECT column_default INTO id_default
               FROM  information_schema.columns
               WHERE table_name = TG_TABLE_NAME AND column_name = 'id';

        -- THIS DOESN'T WORK!
        EXECUTE 'SELECT $1' INTO id_value USING id_default;

        new.id = id_value;
        EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO ' || quote_ident(TG_TABLE_NAME) || ' SELECT ($1).*' USING new;
        RETURN old;
    END IF;

    -- regular UPDATE
    RETURN new;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I'm just missing the step where i read the default value for the id (it's just a nextval() call). Can anyone help out on this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use a placeholder for expressions.

If DEFAULT doesn't have any reference to record data, then you can use EXECUTE statement, but little bit different

```
postgres=# DO $$
DECLARE x text; y text;
BEGIN
   x := (SELECT column_default
             FROM  information_schema.columns
             WHERE table_name = 'omega' AND column_name = 'a');
   EXECUTE 'SELECT ' || x INTO y;
   RAISE NOTICE '%', y;
END; 
$$;
NOTICE:  2
DO
```